# PHP extract (parsing) string

Tags: php, string, parsing

I'm using a regex to check a string for a certain format.

```
preg_match('/^\/answer ([1-9][0-9]*) (.{1,512})$/', $str, $hit, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Using this regex, the posted string needs to have this format:

> /answer n x

n -> an integer > 0

x -> a string, 512 chars maximum

Now how to extract "n" and "x" the easiest way using PHP?
For example:

> /answer 56 this is my sample text

Should lead to:

```
$value1 = 56;
$value2 = "this is my sample text";
```

Comment: What is there in `$hit`?

Comment: $hit is empty. Not necessary.

Comment: `$hit` stores matches. Have you printed it after `preg_match`?

Comment: No need to use `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` then just access `$hit[1]` and `$hit[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Running this simple piece of code

```
<?php
$hit = [];
$str = '/answer 56 this is my sample text';
preg_match('/^\/answer ([1-9][0-9]*) (.{1,512})$/', $str, $hit, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo'<pre>',print_r($hit),'</pre>';
```

Will show you, that `$hit` has following values:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /answer 56 this is my sample text
            [1] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 56
            [1] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => this is my sample text
            [1] => 11
        )

)
1</pre>
```

Here:

- `$hit[0][0]` is full string that matches your pattern
- `$hit[1][0]` is a substring that matches pattern `[1-9][0-9]*`
- `$hit[2][0]` is a substring that matches pattern `.{1,512}`

So,

```
$value1 = $hit[1][0];
$value2 = $hit[2][0];
```